# Searching a firebase database for entry matching two separate values

Tags: angular, firebase, search, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database with some entries that I need to search for the existence of based on the criterion that the matched reference has two children that match the query.

For instance, my database might look like this:

```
{
  "someid" : {
    "date" : "20-7-17",
    "name" : "Bill Bailey",
    "time" : "5:30"
  },
  "someid2" : {
    "date" : "21-5-17",
    "name" : "Fred Malone",
    "time" : "20:00"
  }
}
```

So when I search for "date => 20-7-17, time => 5:30" I should retrieve someid, or really it's just good enough for me to get a true or false to know it exists or if it does not.